# Error in plotting with 2 different y-axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I am trying to re-create a graph two different datasets (Unemployment Rate(left), and Average Hourly Earnings/(GDP/population)) with two different y axis, using ggplot like this image from FRED. Is this possible?
[graph from fred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSbg1.png)

I used this code (see below) but unfortunately it produced a plot (see below) that produces an error. Is there a way to adjust the y axis so we can see two plot together?

Thank you very much for your support.

R code

```
GRA <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=AVG_GDP_POP_RATIO, aes(x=date,y= value/100, color= "AVG_GDP_POP_RATIO"), size = 1.25) +
  geom_line(data=UNRT, aes(x=date,y= value/100, color= "Unemployment Rate"), size = 1.25) +
  scale_y_continuous(name= "AVG_GDP_POP_RATIO", labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1), limits = c(0.015, 0.25), breaks = c(0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25), expand = c(0, 0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~. *1000, name="Percent")) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Percent") +
  theme_x + theme(legend.position = c(.40,.90)) +
  scale_color_manual(name= NULL,values = c("#FFE98F","#00A99D","#FFE98F","#A7ACD9")) +
  theme(legend.key.width =  unit(.82, "cm")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")

ggsave(width = 10, height = 7, dpi = "retina",plot = GRA, "GRA.png", type = "cairo-png")
```

Error:

```
Warning messages:
1: Using ragg device as default. Ignoring `type` and `antialias` arguments 
2: Removed 64 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
```

[R plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VediO.png)

Comment: Adding the second axis is only a decoration. It does not affect the position of the lines in your plot. You need to transform the two data series so that they are visible on approximately the same scale. My guess is that you need to divide `AVG_GDP_POP_RATIO` by about 400000 to get it on the same scale as unemployment rate, so the first line should have `value/400000` instead of `value/100`. Then, your secondary axis needs to have `~. *400000` for the secondary axis to display the correct figures. You might need a different number from 400000, but I can't tell exactly without reproducible data